# Nifi:making one flowfile from splited log flowfiles

Tags: apache-nifi

I want  to  make  log files  for  nifi  processors , i  get them  form tailFail and  split text line by line  then check if it is  error , info  or  warn log  and  route to  executescript processors  but   at this time  i have  5   flowfiles and i want to  unify this split  flowfiles and  write it  in one   flowfile, i tried  to use  merge content  but i think it doesn't  fit my  task.

1. I also  want to  know  if nifi  custom log return log  files for
   all processors  i have added in  my  workflow and is it nessecary to
   add  appenders inside  logback.xml.
2. I  want to  know if it is possible to unify split log data?
   (p.s  i tried   routeonAttriute also  but it doesn't  work for me)
   my  workflow  looks like  this:
   [image]

Comment: can't understand the questions and goal to be achieved...

Comment: I  have severla  flowfiles in queue and i want to  write it in one  flowfile

Comment: i have  configured  my custom  processors in  logback.xml

Comment: i  don't  use  any spesific processor,  is  it  neseccary to use  appenders in  this case

Comment: you are like asking different questions not linked with each other. how merging flow files is connected with logback.xml?

Comment: i know , i want to  import  log data in  flowfile

Comment: and  then save  it

Comment: after reitreving log  data  i want to  put it in one flowfile( p.s  i use  splittext  which  split text  line  by line  and i want to collect this data in  one  flowfile )

Comment: but log file continue growing what is the logic to stop merging of the resulting flow file? maybe better to append splitted lines to the output file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153360/discussion-between-sally-tkhilaishvili-and-daggett).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After splitting lines you can use RouteOnContent to check that line matches regexp.

Then if you want to join lines you can use the following script.

That's just an example:

```js
//get 1000 flow file list from incoming queue but not more then 1000
def ffList = session.get(1000)
if(!ffList)return

ffList.each{ff->
    session.read(ff, {rawIn ->
        //you can write here to a new output flowfile
        //but in this example i will just add content into a plain file on disk
        new File('./logs/warn.log') << rawIn << '\n'
    } as InputStreamCallback)

    session.remove(ff)
}
```

[image]